# How do I use ng-animate in ng-repeat to shrink items on leave?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use the new ng-animate directive, and am struggling to get the desired effect when used with a ng-repeat. I am trying to make items grow when entering, and shrink when leaving. So far the enter is working, but the shrink animation fails.

I have set up a fiddle here so you can see my issue:-

http://jsfiddle.net/rpk98c/6t42M/1/

The relevant HTML is:-

```
<ul>
    <li ng-animate="{enter: 'repeat-enter',
                    leave: 'repeat-leave',
                    move: 'repeat-move'}" ng-click="remove($index)" ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li>
</ul>
```

And the relevant CSS:-

```
.repeat-enter-setup, .repeat-leave-setup, .repeat-move-setup {
-webkit-transition:all linear 1s;
-moz-transition:all linear 1s;
-ms-transition:all linear 1s;
-o-transition:all linear 1s;
transition:all linear 1s;
}

.repeat-enter-setup {
    max-height: 0;
    opacity:0;
}
.repeat-enter-setup.repeat-enter-start {
    max-height: 250px;
    opacity:1;
}
.repeat-leave-setup {
    opacity:1;
    max-height: 250px;
}
.repeat-leave-setup.repeat-leave-start {
    opacity:0;
    max-height: 0;
}
```

Anyone know where I've gone wrong?

Thanks,

Ryan

ps just noticed in IE 10 no animations work! I'm testing in Chrome for now

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing it in code, but I have added an updated fiddle doing the desired animations in jQuery here which works. http://jsfiddle.net/rpk98c/cZy7S/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to switch the first line of the css to affect the "start" classes instead of the setup ones. I know, that's not how they do the examples but it will work. So make it:

```
.repeat-enter-start, .repeat-leave-start, .repeat-move-start {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 1s;
  -moz-transition:all linear 1s;
  -ms-transition:all linear 1s;
  -o-transition:all linear 1s;
  transition:all linear 1s;
}
```

This helps because you are trying to animate a property that the element does not usually possess. Elements will not usually have the max-height property set at all. So when you apply a max-height at the same time as the transition *it will animate the fact that you added the property*! This is before the "start" class is even applied which means that the setup stage will not be finished (since the animation takes 1 second) before the start stage is supposed to begin. So when you apply the "leave" animation the following steps will happen.

1. You element starts without a max-height.
2. The "leave-setup" class is applied and gives you max-height and a transition.
3. Because the max-height just "changed" (from not existing to existing) and you have a transition the browser will now start to animate the max-height from some default starting value (0 it seems) to your chosen value of 250px, so the element immediately shrinks to 0 and starts animating up!
4. Now the "leave-start" class is applied, but step 3 is not done yet! The max-height is still 0, or close to, since it is still busy animating the inserting of the property, so the animation just stops and goes to 0 again and we never see anything.

But if we move the transition property from the "setup"-step to the "start"-step, like in the css above, step 3 will be instant since it has no transition. The transition appears first at step 4. So we have:

1. You element starts without a max-height.
2. The "leave-setup" class is applied and gives you max-height *but not* transition.
3. We have no transition so the max height is just instantly changed to 250px.
4. Now the "leave-start" class is applied, and since step 3 is finished this time around the max-height is now 250px and we can animate away from that without issues.

You don't have this problem with opacity since you are animating from the default value of 1, there is no animation to get in the way in step 3. It also seems that enter events are handled a bit differently since they are more likely to animate from a non-default value, so you will not see this behavior on ever events.

Edit:

I experimented a bit more with this and it turns out my answer does not work for Firefox (at least not on FF Windows). First of all FF seems to just straight up fail if you animate a non existing property, so you need to make sure that your elements have a max-height from the start, something like:

```
li {
    max-height: 250px;
}
```

This fixes leave for me, but for some reason no enter animation at all will work in Firefox on windows. Still trying to figure that one out.

Comment: Also, note that because you have a max-height that is much larger than the element the animation for the fade out and the slide up will appear to be out of sync. We only see the tail end of the animation. Set a lower max-height to fix this, or if you don't know the final height of the element try animating using line-height instead. It does not look quite the same but it is close.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why to specify `max-height`.
You can ommit all the height specificiation and it seems working.

```
.repeat-enter-setup, .repeat-leave-setup, .repeat-move-setup {
-webkit-transition:all linear 1s;
-moz-transition:all linear 1s;
-ms-transition:all linear 1s;
-o-transition:all linear 1s;
transition:all linear 1s;
}

.repeat-enter-setup {
    opacity:0;
}
.repeat-enter-setup.repeat-enter-start {
    opacity:1;
}
.repeat-leave-setup {
    opacity:1;
}
.repeat-leave-setup.repeat-leave-start {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The max-height is an attempt to make the items grow / shrink as part of the animation. Removing it means the opacity animates then you get a jump in height. See jsfiddle.net/rpk98c/cZy7S/2 for the desired effect. I was hoping I could do this in CSS. Thanks Ryan

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is a bit out of date now, but it was still really helpful as I worked through this same problem. Here's an example of an expand/collapse functionality using the latest versions of ng-animate and the `limitTo` filter on `ng-repeat`:

HTML:

```
<div ng-init="listLimit = 3">
    <div class="expander" ng-repeat="item in list | limitTo: listLimit">
        {{ item }}
    </div>
    <div ng-click="listLimit === 3 ? listLimit = list.length : listLimit = 3">
        <span ng-if="listLimit === 3">more</span>
        <span ng-if="listLimit !== 3">less</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.expander {
  max-height: 250px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all linear 0.8s;
}

.expander.ng-enter {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.expander.ng-enter-active {
  max-height: 250px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.expander.ng-leave {
  max-height: 250px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.expander.ng-leave-active {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```